# Convert video to hequirect while setting the background black and blur the transitional area

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "v360=input=fisheye:ih_fov=122.6:iv_fov=94.4:output=hequirect:h_fov=180:v_fov=180:in_stereo=2d:out_stereo=sbs,format=yuv420p" -b:v 25M -maxrate 60M -bufsize 25M output.mp4
```

Which works as advertised to convert a fisheye to hequirect except for two problems:

1. The background is not black but seems to try and set it to the average color of the video. It should be black throughout.
2. The corners are not blurred but should be, there should be a soft transition from the corner of the video into black.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)